# What is the function of this jquery syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across the following `jquery` syntax

```
var some_variable = $("<input>").attr("type", "some type").attr("name", "some name").val(JSON.stringify(someobj));
```

I want to know what the `$("<input>")` syntax is doing? what is the meaning of `<` , `>` sign in here?

Comment: `what is the meaning of < , > sign in here` This means that it is not a selector, just a raw html

Comment: That syntax is used to create a new element

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in the jQuery object of your example is used to create a new element, in this case an `input`. Also note that you can set the properties in a single jQuery object instead of chaining multiple `attr()` calls:

```
$("<input>", {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'name', 
    value: JSON.stringify({ abc: 123 })
});
```

Comment: It isn't a selector. It is HTML.

Comment: weren't there specific caveats with using the property syntax with `<input>` elements in MSIE ?

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2):

> `jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )`
> Description: Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<input'>)
```

would be used to create a new, non-existing html tag of the type 'input'.

See this for further documentation:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

It creates an `input` element.

[It  http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)

Answer (score 0):

That syntax creates a new `input` element, adds some attributes to it, assigns a value to it. Now, you have an `input` element which is just not attached to DOM. You can use jQuery's `append`, `appendTo` or other insertion methods to attach it anywhere you like in your html DOM.